# Removing from a Haystack/Xapian Index with update_index --remove

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm trying to have the `./manage.py update_index --remove` management command remove results from the search index.

I'd like to remove the objects, not when they are deleted, just when their:

```
enabled = models.BooleanField()
```

field is `False`

What do I do here? Do I need to prepare the SearchIndex in anyway?

```
import datetime
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from articles.models import Article

class ArticleIndex(SearchIndex):

    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = CharField(model_attr='title')
    content = CharField(model_attr='content')

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Article.site_published_objects.filter(enabled=True)

    def get_updated_field(self):
        return 'modified'

    def remove_object(self):
        pass

site.register(Article, ArticleIndex)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tested this, but you might be able to achieve the desired effect by wrapping your search index template in a condition, e.g.:

```
{# in search/indexes/yourapp/article_text.txt #}
{% if object.enabled %}
    {# ... whatever you have now #}
{% endif %}
```

When you run `./manage.py update_index`, articles with `enabled=False` will end up with no data associated to it and not show up in searches.

#### Update

Looking at the source for `SearchIndex`, there a [`remove_object()`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/914a9baf/haystack/indexes.py#L219) method for removing an object from the index. There's also the [`should_update()`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/914a9baf/haystack/indexes.py#L262) which is run to determine if an object's index should be updated.

Perhaps it's possible to trigger the index removal using something like:

```
class ArticleIndex(SearchIndex):
    # ...

    def should_update(self, instance, **kwargs):
        if not instance.enabled:
            self.remove_object(instance, **kwargs)
        return instance.enabled
```

Comment: Ok I like it, and will probably use this -- failing being able to remove objects 'properly' from the index.  Got any ideas there?

Comment: @Daryl Yes, one more. Updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant @Shawn! -- Look forward to giving this a run :)